# Reference an existing panel in Grafana

Tags: influxdb, grafana, telegraf

I'd like to know if it's possible to build an 'overview' type of dashboard which references other panels in a different dashboard.

I have a very detailed dashboard that contains a lot of statistics for the system and would like to extract only CPU and Network for a new dashboard that will be displaying this same stats for multiple systems (with the same data in each). Is it possible to 'reference' an existing object? Or do I need to re-create each panel as a copy of the formula from the source?

I'm on the latests Grafana 4 with InfluxDB datasource and Telegraf for collecting stats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's currently not possible in Grafana(4.2.0).

The best solution right now is to use https://github.com/utkarshcmu/wizzy and copy panels between dashboards.